# How to check at least one selected checkbox using form validation jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<body>
    <form id="applicationForm" method="POST" class="valida en" action="../../lib/air-condition-request.php">
    <label class="serviceDay">
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConDaily">Daily 
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConMon" name="monday" value="1">Monday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConTue" name="tuesday" value='1'>Tuesday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConWed" name="wednesday" value='1'>Wednesday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConThur" name="thursday" value='1'>Thursday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConFri" name="friday" value='1'>Friday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConSat" name="saturday" value='1'>Saturday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConSun" name="sunday" value='1'>Sunday
    <input type="checkbox" id="airConPh" name="ph" value='1'> Public Holiday
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="2">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="all-btn">
    </form>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/form-validation.js"></script>
</body>
```

form-validation jquery

```
$('#itemForm').validate({
  errorClass:"validationError",
    rules:{
    
    },
    messages:{
      
    }
  

});
```

Hello all,

I check many answers about at least one selected checkbox but they cannot solve my question.

How the system shows error if the the user does not choose any checkbox.

Thank you

Comment: A basic condition would be `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0` but I don't know how to incorporate that with jQuery validate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it fits your Use Case but you can give your Checkboxes all the same name and give them different values, in your validation you then do a simple required check

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConTue" name="weekday" value='tuesday'>Tuesday
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConWed" name="weekday" value='wednesday'>Wednesday
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConThur" name="weekday" value='thursday'>Thursday
```

```js
rules: {
  weekday: {required: !0}
}
```

Edit: What might even be better if you did an array, as this will make serialization easier!

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConTue" name="weekday[]" value='tuesday'>Tuesday
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConWed" name="weekday[]" value='wednesday'>Wednesday
  <input type="checkbox" id="airConThur" name="weekday[]" value='thursday'>Thursday
```

```js
rules: {
  "weekday[]": {required: !0}
}
```

Comment: I try this method before. There is no error message.

Comment: https://github.com/Shumuu/jqv this worked for me. If you can't find your mistake, could you share a repo where it does not show a message for you ?